# How to apply position sticky on a div based on its innerText?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'd like to set the `position: sticky` when the `innerText` of the `.newsDate` is the same as the previous or the next `.newsDate`, onScroll, until reaching the next, aside the `.newsMiddleCont` div.

What's the goal:

> With several news items, the same date can remain sticky if they were published on the same day

I have the code below, which is not working the way I would like it to.

It adds and removes `sticky` `position` to all of the `.newsDate`, and not while the `.newsMiddleCont` is visible, and regardless whether the classes are or aren't the same based on the `innerText`.

**EDIT:**

A bit more explanation:

**The sticky has to depend on the date inside `.newsDate`.**

*In my example html, the first "28. September 2022." has to stay sticky until it reaches the second "28. September 2022."; and beyond until it reaches "13. October 1999.", then it should lose the sticky and change to static. And then this should happen again in a similar scenario.*

**IMPORTANT:**

> Dates have a unique scrolling animation. As we scroll down, the date comes with us in sticky mode. If the date of the next article is the same, it (the date) goes on to that post as well. If the date of the next post is different, the date stops at the bottom of the corresponding post and continues scrolling with the post.

The "scrolling animation" refers to the scrolling behavior (stay still and/or move along). "It" is the date. If the second date is the same as the first, the date scrolls to the next "post". If the date different the date stops at the end of the post, and as we scroll it (the date) goes along with the post, then out of the viewport with the post.

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var previousDate = null;

  $('.newsLeftCont').each(function() {
    var newsLeftCont = $(this);
    var newsDate = newsLeftCont.find('.newsDate');
    var isElementVisible = isElementInViewport(newsLeftCont);

    if (isElementVisible && newsDate.text().trim() !== previousDate) {
      newsLeftCont.addClass('sticky');
      previousDate = newsDate.text().trim();
    } else {
      newsLeftCont.removeClass('sticky');
    }

    var nextNewsMiddleCont = newsLeftCont.next('.newsMiddleCont');
    if (nextNewsMiddleCont.length && isElementInViewport(nextNewsMiddleCont)) {
      newsLeftCont.removeClass('sticky');
    }
  });
});

function isElementInViewport(element) {
  var rect = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  return rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= $(window).height();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.newsCont {
  max-width: 870px;
  min-height: 756px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.newsLeftCont {
  height: 222px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 8px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.newsLeftContInner {
  align-self: stretch;
  padding-top: 16px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 8px;
  display: flex;
  height: 160px;
}

.newsDate {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  color: #F05663;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 140px;
  border-right: 0.50px #D6D6D6 solid;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 37px;
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.newsMiddleCont {
  padding-left: 56px;
  padding-right: 56px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  left: 76px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #242424;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 16px;
  display: inline-flex
}

.newsLeftCont {
  position: static;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="sec_pub">
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">13. October 1999.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">13. October 1999.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">13. October 1999.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Any reason why it has to be sticky? IMO this could be easily solved using fixed instead, the problem with sticky is that it will not be sticky to the window (meaning it can't get out of `newsCont`, and you need it to get out of it)

Comment: @Damzaky It just needs to be sticky... don't ask why. But my logic would dictate the same as yours.

Comment: @Damzaky I've updated my question with: **Dates have a unique scrolling animation. As we scroll down, the date comes with us in sticky mode. If the date of the next article is the same, it goes on to that post as well. If the date of the next post is different, the date stops at the bottom of the corresponding post and continues scrolling with the post.**

Comment: honestly, I feel like my answer already does that, unless I misunderstand something. Does this 'If the second date is the same as the first, the date scrolls with the "post"' mean that if the **second date** is same as first, you want the **second date** to scroll together with the first date (on top of each other)?

Comment: @Damzaky sorry, I meant: "If the second date is the same as the first, the date scrolls to the next "post".

Comment: ok, please check my edited answer, it now should be according to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope, I understood your question correctly... I suggest changing the html a little, and for the date use `writing-mode: vertical-lr;` + `transform: rotate(180deg);`.
Here's what your code might look like:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.sec_pub {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 64px;
}

.newsCont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  max-width: 870px;
  color: white;
}

.newsLeftCont {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
  border-inline-end: solid 1px #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  margin-inline: 20px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  align-self: start;
  color: #F05663;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.newsContPosts {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 96px;
}

.newsMiddleCont {
  padding: 40px 56px;
  background: #242424;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
}
```

```html
<section class="sec_pub">
 <div class="newsCont">
    <div class="newsLeftCont">27. September 2022.</div>
    <div class="newsContPosts">
    <div class="newsMiddleCont">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
      vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
      morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
      velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
      aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
      in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
      tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
    </div>
    <div class="newsMiddleCont">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
      vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
      morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
      velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
      aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
      in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
      tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="newsCont">
    <div class="newsLeftCont">28. September 2022.</div>
    <div class="newsContPosts">
    <div class="newsMiddleCont">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
      vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
      morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
      velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
      aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
      in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
      tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="newsCont">
    <div class="newsLeftCont">29. September 2022.</div>
    <div class="newsContPosts">
    <div class="newsMiddleCont">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
      vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
      morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
      velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
      aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
      in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
      tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
    </div>
    <div class="newsMiddleCont">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
      vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
      morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
      velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
      aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
      in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
      tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
    </div>
    <div class="newsMiddleCont">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
      vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
      morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
      velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
      aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
      in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
      tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="newsCont">
    <div class="newsLeftCont">30. September 2022.</div>
    <div class="newsContPosts">
    <div class="newsMiddleCont">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
      vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
      morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
      velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
      aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
      in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
      tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
    </div>
    <div class="newsMiddleCont">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
      vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
      morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
      velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
      aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
      in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
      tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, using the top property, the fixed element can be positioned to look like it's sticky. Remember to update your CSS accordingly.

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  // Get all the news items.
  let newsItems = $(".newsCont");

  newsItems.each(function(index) {
// Get the current news date.
let currentDate = $(this).find(".newsDate").text().trim();

// Calculate the scroll top position.
let topPosition = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

// If the current date is '28. September 2022.', 
// and the topPosition is less or equal to 0, then add the sticky class.
if (currentDate === '28. September 2022.' && topPosition <= 0) {
  $(this).find(".newsLeftCont").addClass("sticky");
} else {
  // Otherwise, remove the sticky class.
  $(this).find(".newsLeftCont").removeClass("sticky");
}
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.newsCont {
  max-width: 870px;
  min-height: 756px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.newsLeftCont {
  height: 222px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 8px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.newsDate {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  color: #F05663;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 140px;
  border-right: 0.50px #D6D6D6 solid;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 37px;
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.newsMiddleCont {
  padding-left: 56px;
  padding-right: 56px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  left: 76px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #242424;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 16px;
  display: inline-flex
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="sec_pub">
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">13. October 1999.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">13. October 1999.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">13. October 1999.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I can only use sticky - that's the point of the task, from static to sticky, and based on the `.newsDate`'s `innerText`.

Comment: Yes i know, i changed my answer.

Comment: The `position: fixed` passed my mind, but that's not what I need.

Comment: The `.newsLeftCont` should be "getting & losing" sticky, based on the `innerText` of the `.newsDate`.

Comment: How about now? Fixed the getting

Comment: The sticky has to depend on the date inside `.newsDate`. In my example html, the first "28. September 2022." has to stay sticky until it reaches beyond the the second "28. September 2022." , then when the it reaches "13. October 1999." it should lose the sticky and change to static. And then this happens again, but only in similar scenario.

Comment: it's a bit tricky because you're using `position: sticky;` which means that the element will stick to the top of the viewport until it's containing block (i.e., the nearest ancestor with `position: relative;`) has been scrolled out of the viewport.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254475/discussion-between-jagmitg-and-iorgv).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've updated my question.

Comment: @iorgv updated based on your specific requirements.

Answer (score -3):

I have made my version of the problem you have given.
This is only some small changes made

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var previousDate = null;

  $('.newsLeftCont').each(function() {
    var newsLeftCont = $(this);
    var newsDate = newsLeftCont.find('.newsDate');
    var isElementVisible = isElementInViewport(newsLeftCont);

    newsLeftCont.addClass('sticky');
    
    if (isElementVisible && newsDate.text().trim().toLowerCase() !== previousDate) {
      newsLeftCont.addClass('sticky');
      previousDate = newsDate;
    } else if(previousDate != null) {
      previousDate.removeClass('sticky');
    }
  });
});

function isElementInViewport(element) {
  var rect = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  return rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= $(window).height();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.newsCont {
  max-width: 870px;
  min-height: 756px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.newsLeftCont {
  height: 222px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 8px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.newsLeftContInner {
  align-self: stretch;
  padding-top: 16px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 8px;
  display: flex;
  height: 160px;
}

.newsDate {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  color: #F05663;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 140px;
  border-right: 0.50px #D6D6D6 solid;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 37px;
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.newsMiddleCont {
  padding-left: 56px;
  padding-right: 56px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  left: 76px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #242424;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 16px;
  display: inline-flex
}

.newsLeftCont {
  position: static;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="sec_pub">
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">13. October 1999.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">13. October 1999.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">13. October 1999.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Pharetra magna ac placerat
        vestibulum lectus. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor. Neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Ullamcorper
        morbi tincidunt ornare massa. Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum
        velit euismod. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.<br>Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Enim nulla
        aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere. Arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem donec. Auctor elit sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Ante
        in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Sed elementum
        tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Magna etiam tempor orci eu. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've updated my question.